# How to know what will execute at startup/bootup?

Tags: boot, directory-structure, services, reboot

I would like what scripts will run at start, without needing to "restart and see what happens", is there any way to know what 'services' are ready to run?

Shoud I check every single file in

```
ls /etc/rc0.d
...
and so on?
```

or just

```
reboot
```

Missing DOS autoexec.bat.......

**EDIT**

I am using Debian

Comment: Reboot is runlevel 6.  What OS are you using?

Comment: As Karlson mention, we need to know which OS your using (solaris, centos, ubuntu, etc). Are you looking for (1)What will be run when a machine startup/bootup? (2) What will be run when you hit the command `reboot`?

Comment: @JohnSiu I am looking for (1), thanks

Answer (score 2):

Trouble is, there has been quite a bit of turmoil in the system init area recently. Can't really comment autoritatively on all of them.

For "traditional" SysVinit, you have a bunch of directories `/etc/rcX.d`, where X ranges from 0 up to <max> which depends on the distribution's vagaries. The file `/etc/inittab` states the default runlevel (normally "full graphics environment", on Fedora/Red Hat at least it is/was 5). With that, you go dig into `/etc/rc5.d` (in this case), where you will find a farm of symlinks called `KNNsomething` and `SNNsomethingelse`. The `K` is for kill, you are interested in the `S` ones, for start. The number `NN` is a precedence (in which sequence to start/stop stuff is gigne by them). The `something` or `somethingelse`are descriptive names for the service. The `chkconfig --list` command lists the same (OK, those it knows about, something nasty might have snuck in there...). The scripts themselves are *not* for the faint of heart. It has been said that reading them causes eye cancer in laboratory sysadmins.

Newer systems use [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com) (Ubuntu, some others), Fedora uses [`systemd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd), Debian I believe offers several alternatives, and so do some of the minor distributions (some might even have their own system). MacOS and Solaris have their own idiosincratic service management. But in several Linux distributions the migration from `sysvinit` isn't complete (on current Fedora, which spearheads `systemd`, there are still older scripts around, and `systemd` knows how to use them).

I'm no `systemd` expert, but that system is a lot more flexible than just "runlevels", you can have several `targets` (e.g., graphical desktop, database server, web server) and mix and match. `systemctl list-units --type=target` tells you which ones are configured, `systemctl list-units` tells you all the stuff that is currently active.

For others, you'll have to wait for somebody knowledgeable editing them in here (or commenting).